# Why does ploro mean lament, but exploro means explore?

Tags: etymology

The root word *ploro* means to lament. So, for example, *deploro* means to cry over or despair, and *imploro* means to beseech. However, *exploro* means explore or search out and  appears to be completely unrelated to ploro. What is the explanation for this?

Answer (score 7):

According to De Vaan:

> No etymology [going back to PIE]. [Walde-Hofmann] and [Ernout and Meillet] regard the ancient explanation as not unlikely, viz. that the verb *explōrāre* originally meant 'to scout the hunting area for game by means of shouting'.

This seems like a bit of a stretch to me, but I haven't found anything more likely.

Comment: Walde-Hoffmann and  Ernout-Meillet of course.

Comment: @fdb I was planning to add some more detail about those etymological dictionaries but I realize that's probably better served by a different question that someone other than me can answer. I've never actually used 'em myself (only seen them as sources for other things) so I've just expanded the abbreviations for now.

Comment: @Draconis: Just curious, if you didn't use either of those, what did you use? I mean before De Vaan.

Comment: @Cerberus De Vaan's the main source I've ever used; I wasn't really doing anything with etymology before 2011. There was another book focusing on all the Italic languages (so still like 90% Latin) that I'm trying to find again, but I never had specifically an etymological dictionary before De Vaan.

Comment: @Draconis: Ah, OK, I understand.

Comment: @Cerberus That said, I know others in the field are less than satisfied with De Vaan overall, so I'm definitely interested in [learning more about these other works](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/18809/406)!

Comment: @Draconis: Good idea, I didn't know we didn't have a question like that.