# What etymological dictionaries of Latin are there?

Tags: etymology, resource-request

In many cases, I want to look up cognates or PIE reconstructions for Latin words, and it would be nice to have a more scholarly source than Wiktionary.

What are the standard reference works in this field? Note that I'm looking specifically for *etymologies* here rather than definitions.

(Personally, I have a PDF copy of De Vaan 2011, though Alex B. has pointed me to [a scathing critique of it](https://kratylos.reichert-online.org/article/KRATYLOS/2012/1/1) by Vine. De Vaan frequently cites IEW, WH, EM, and LIV, and I'm curious if others use/have used those and can say more about them—or if there are others I'm missing. But I don't want to focus the question specifically on any of these in particular because a general resource-request question could be valuable for others as well.)

Comment: Now I'm curious, what are the main points of criticism on De Vaan? I cannot access this critique.